# Android Gmail-like drawer account selection

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, drawerlayout

I'm fine with the Gmail Drawer layout (header with image, drawer items with icon, separators etc.) but a feature I can't understand is about the account manage/selection available like a spinner in the drawer. I don't know if it's a spinner or what. I have implemented a spinner in the drawer but it has not the same behaviour like the Gmail feature.

On Gmail, pressing on the little red-circled corner it will show/hide a "pane" over the whole drawer. To be more clear I give you two screen showing this feature.

[image: This is before clicking]

[image: This is after clicking]

Anyone knows how this can be implemented?

Comment: It's just swapping out that lower layout. You could do something similar by creating two inner layouts and toggling their visibility, setting one to `GONE` and the other to `VISIBLE`, and toggling the arrow image upon clicking.

Comment: You're probably right, just simpler than I thought